# What are $A$ and $k_0$ in this effective mass equation?

Tags: mass, momentum, dispersion

I have the equation:

$$E=A(k-k_0)^2$$

I am trying to find effective mass with the equation:

$$m^*=\frac{h^2k^2}{2A(k-k_0)^2}$$

I know that $k$ is momentum, and I assume $k_0$ is minimum momentum, but I don't know how to get it.

I don't know what $A$ is, my book doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics.SE! Could you provide more context to your question (wave, quantum mechanics)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effective mass is defined around a minimum of a dispersion curve. It is, essentially, how heavy an electron would have to be so that electrons occupying these states can be described by free electrons.

$ko$ (I'd still say that's a $k_0$) is the momentum where the parabola is centered, $2A$ is the curvature at the bottom of this parabola, as is easily seen from the equation for $E$.

There seems to be something off with your formula for the effective mass. If you look at any solid state physics book, you will see
$$ m^* = \hbar \left[\left.\frac{d^2E}{dk^2}\right|_{k=k_0}\right]^{-1} = \frac{\hbar}{2A}$$
which makes sense because the effective mass as described above should not depend on $k$.